# Rewriting GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite $_GET parameters via .htaccess. I have tried doing it myself but no success. Check what I want below:

```
mydomain.com/system.php?id=748742
```

to

```
mydomain.com/system/748742
```

My /var/www/ directory: prntscr.com/ixpt1x

I have tried using this rule but my server keeps saying 500 Internal Server Error

```
RewriteRule ^system/(.*) /system.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here is my .htaccess file at this current time

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico images/favicon.ico [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 403 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 404.php
```

Comment: And "no success" means what _exactly_ ? What does your http servers error log file say what the issue is?

Comment: "no success" means that my goal was not achieved. I'm trying to rewrite these URL's but still not working no matter what I do. I'm trying to check my server logs but I believe that my host keeps excluding them automatically

Comment: How to you want to debug your systems without access to the log files?

Comment: You need to add that new line rewriting the `/system` URL _before_ the last existing rewrite rule.

Comment: It's working! But the images does not appear lol. Seems to be that this rule is rewriting the images too

Comment: Sure, if the URLs referencing those images also start with `/system`, then you need to refine that rule. Probably something like `RewriteRule ^/?system/(\d+)/?$ /system.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`...

Comment: I'm getting 404 error now, might the rule is broken. @edit: The images are bringed from images/ folder, does not begin from /system

Comment: From your example I assume that the `id` get argument can contain only digits? Then the rule is fine.

Comment: The images does not starts with /system, they are included in /images folder

Comment: Ah, then you miss interpreted my comment about the placement of the new rule. I will post an answer to clear things up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167766/discussion-between-amazing-man-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of the discussion in the comments to the question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico images/favicon.ico [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?system/(\d+)/?$ /system.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 403 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 404.php
```

Comment: The "system" in the URL still persists: mysite.com/system/images/poster/455568242.png. Removing the "system" works perfeclty

Comment: @Amazingman In the comment to the question you claimed that those images are _not_ contained under the `/system/` URL prefix. Now you say they are...

Comment: @Amazingman Anyway, could you please elaborate your last comment? I don't understand what you try to express with that...

Comment: I'm trying to say that the images are bringed from images/ folder, but it's not only this, it's rewritting css and js files too

Comment: @Amazingman Your comments are vague, confusing. Please add a URL layout tree to your question.

Comment: @Amazingman Well, certainly the other two rewriting rules might rewrite requests to paths like `/css` and the like. I assume those rules are working and desired, since you did not comment on them. Though I have to say that they look strange and confusing to me. But the rule rewriting the `/system/` prefixed URLs certainly does _not_ rewrite requests to images and style sheets.

Comment: The other two rewriting rules just remove .php extension and redirect automatically to avoid removing them manually

Comment: Yes and no. The first one, the one using the `RewriteCond`.. why that special condition? The could be a simple one liner. And the last one... Why the `(/|)$` ? Why not simply `/?$` ? This all looks as if you copied rules from all over google...

Comment: And again I have _no_ idea what you mean by " to avoid removing them manually". You need to be _precise_ in your statements. Like this we could go on forever.

Comment: "to avoid removing them manually" means deleting the .php extensions in <a href="mypage.php"> tag, for example

Comment: That will leave you with a horrible mess of references getting rewritten again and again. A _very_ bad idea. That rule does _not_ magically fix the references you send out.

Comment: But the problem with the rule that I mentioned in this thread is that, after rewriting the URL, a slash is added after "system", and the page believe that all components are inside this "system /" folder, which is actually a php file

Comment: Also thanks for these tips, I'll figure out a new ideas how to improve them

Comment: Ah, so you are talking about relative references. The new rule in the form I posted will _not_ add a trailing slash to anything. It specifically rewrites to an internal path ending in `.php`, doesn''t it? It _might_ be that your script referenced that way tries to be smart and hands out references with a `/system/` prefix. But if so, then that has nothing to do with the rewriting rule, but with how that script is implemented.

Comment: Then I'll fix how my script is implemented. A last question, do you know how to redirect automatically _mydomain.com/system.php?id=748742_ to _mydomain.com/system/748742_? It only works if I insert in manually on the browser

Comment: You do not want to do that, it only superficially hides issues with your implementation and will cause confusion, caching issues and rank penalty by search robots. If you want to, then take a look at the rule you already implemented yourself, then one with the condition. Although it is strangely complicated it does what you ask: it results in an external redirection. You'd only need to adapt the initial matching pattern.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Have fun with your project!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico images/favicon.ico [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^/?system/(\d+)/?$ /system.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 404.php
ErrorDocument 403 404.php
ErrorDocument 500 404.php
```